# Dependent dropdown in dhtmlx scheduler lightbox

Tags: lightbox, dhtmlx-scheduler

is it possible to use a dependent dropdown in Lightbox?
See:
http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightbox API allows you defining custom controls, so you should be able to create a lightbox wrapper for jQuery dependent dropdown.

Here is related docs article:
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/custom_lightbox_editor.html

Also, there is a working example if dependent dropdowns implemented in plain js/html in scheduler samples package:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/02_customization/26_linked_selects_in_lightbox.html

Comment: Can I transform the selects to `Jquery` `select2` fields?
Or to `autocomplete combobox`?

Comment: I'd try implementing it with jquery select2, though. I think it'll be more flexible than the built-in combo. 
You'll have to wrap jquery control into a custom lightbox control. 
Here are small examples with jquery chosen  
http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/f4f83b015
and jquery select2
http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/a755f4ebe

In order to make a dependent control from it, you'll need to add two such controls to the lightbox (sample http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/88168a426), then listen to onchange event of the top dropdown and update options of the bottom dropdown based on parent selection

Comment: Thanks Alex, very helpful! The examples are always with `multiselect`. Is there a way to disable `multiselect`?

Comment: You can change it in `form_blocks[...].render` method, just remove `multiple` attribute from select element html: http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/c79bddcc8

Comment: Thanks Alex... I am fighting now with `optionsconnector` and `yii2`. Can you have a look on this topic? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150808/yii2-with-dhtmlx-scheduler-and-select-populated-from-the-server]

Comment: sure, I've posted an answer there. Not sure how helpful it is, tbh, I've never worked with yii2 framework