# yii2 with dhtmlx scheduler and select populated from the server

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am trying to populate the project select dropdown with data from the server.
I am using yii2.

My controller data action:

```
public function actionData()
{
    $list = new OptionsConnector(null, "PHPYii");
    $list->render_table("project", "id", "id(value),name(label)");
    $connector = new JSONSchedulerConnector(null, "PHPYii");
    $connector->set_options("project", $list);
    $connector->configure(
        new Booking(), "id", "start, end, activity, user, subsubproject, status, comment"
    );
    $connector->render();
}
```

I get an error message:

> Exception 'Error' with message 'Call to a member function find() on
>   string'

And I think this line is the cause: `$connector->set_options("project", $list);`

What should I change?

UPDATE:
So I am here now:

```
public function actionData() {
    $list = new JSONOptionsConnector(null, "PHPYii");
    $list->enable_log("text1.log");
    $list->configure(
        new Subsubproject(),
            "-","id, name"
    );
    $list->render();
    $connector = new JSONSchedulerConnector(null, "PHPYii");
    $connector->enable_log("text2.log");
    $connector->set_options("subsubprojects", $list);
    $connector->configure(
        new Booking(),
            "id", "start, end, activity, user, subsubproject, status,comment"
    );
    $connector->render();
}
```

and I get this:

```
0: Object { key: undefined, id: 1, name: "Thing1", … }
​1: Object { key: undefined, id: 2, name: "Thing2", … }
​2: Object { key: undefined, id: 3, name: "Thing3", … }
```

I don't have keys... How can I get some? :)

Comment: please select the answer if it worked for you as a good gesture towards the user who gave you some time out of their own to solve YOUR problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't need to call the render method of JSONOptionsConnector directly. Calling it ends processing of the request if I'm not mistaken, so the SchedulerConnector takes no effect
Try commenting out `$list->render();` line.

2) The response format seems a bit off. This may be a bug of PHPYii wrapper of dhtmlx connector, I'm not sure

According to [source codes](https://github.com/DHTMLX/scheduler/blob/v5.1.6/codebase/sources/dhtmlxscheduler.js#L6126) the client-side needs `value` and `label` properties from options, and while handler returns `id` and `name`.

You can try something following:

```
public function actionData() {
    $list = new JSONOptionsConnector(null, "PHPYii");
    $list->enable_log("text1.log");
    $list->configure(
        new Subsubproject(),
            "id","id(value), name(label)"
            // or 
            // "id(value)","id(value), name(label)"
    );

    $connector->enable_log("text2.log");
    $connector->set_options("subsubprojects", $list);
    $connector->configure(
        new Booking(),
            "id", "start, end, activity, user, subsubproject, status,comment"
    );
    $connector->render();
}
```

This should produce a json response containing a list of booking and subprojects.
However, I can't test this code so something may still be wrong.
You can try it and see whether the result JSON looks right.

If it doesn't get you any closer, I honestly would produce json manually rather than using a connector with `PHPYii` wrapper. That way you'll have direct control over what is returned from your controller and won't have another black box there.

You'll need to return a json of the following structure from your action:
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/data_formats.html#jsonwithcollections

so you'll have something like this in your action:

```
return $this->asJson([
  "data"=> $preparedEventsArray
  "collections" => [
      "subprojects"=> $preparedSubprojects
   ]
]);
```

where $preparedEventsArray is an array of event objects as shown in docs, and $subprojects - your value/label objects

Note that names of properties in the `data` collection -  "id","start_date","end_date","text" - are mandatory, you'll have to map your data model to this structure,
e.g.

```
start -> start_date
end -> end_date
activity -> text
```

all other properties can have their names unchanged.

The official docs don't have a sample code for Yii2, unfortunately. 
There are common docs for server formats
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/server_integration.html
And tutorials for PHP [Slim](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/howtostart_php.html) framework and [Laravel](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/howtostart_php_laravel.html), which is not exactly what you need, but the closest thing the current documentation has.